# Do I need to poll nonblocking sockets for better performance?

Tags: sockets, asynchronous, nonblocking, recv

I have a list of nonblocking sockets.

I could call `recv` in each one (in this case, some calls shall fail) or `poll` the list and later call `recv` on ready sockets.

Is there a performance difference between these approaches?

Thanks!

Comment: If you call recv in a loop then you're never letting go of the processor. You should use epoll in edge-triggered more for best performance.

Comment: I could have a loop like `{ recv(); other_tasks(); }` or `{ poll(); recv(); other_tasks(); }`. Is there a performance difference between these loops?

Comment: The poll call will sleep while consuming zero CPU if there's nothing to do immediately. This is very desirable. The only case where it wouldn't help is if you're writing a game which runs at 100% CPU anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the rate of data on the sockets is quite high (eg: `recv()` will fail <25% of the time), using `poll()` or `select()` is almost always the better choice.

Modern operating system will intelligent block a `poll()` operation until one of fds in the set is ready (the kernel will block the thread on a set of fds, awaking it only when that fd has been accessed... ultimately, this happens far more than necessary, resulting in some busy-waiting, but it's better than nothing), while a `recv()` loop will always result in busy waiting.

Comment: Can a recv call on a nonblocking socket result in busy waiting?

Comment: It will **always** result in busy waiting if no data is available... a `recv()` on a non-blocking socket is constantly saying "Is there data on this socket? No. Okay, go back to the beginning of the loop.  Is there data on this socket? No. Okay, go back to the beginning of this loop.  Is there [...]".  When you use `poll()`, you gave the OS a chance to rest.

Comment: Ok. But if `recv` is not in a loop it won't result in busy waiting, right?

Comment: Consider these 2 loops: `{ recv(); other_tasks(); }` and `{ poll(); recv(); other_tasks(); }`. None of them will result in busy waiting with nonblocking sockets and setting `poll` timeout to 0, right? Thanks!!

Comment: The difference is a difference in functionality -- if you use `poll()`, your code will not execute `other_tasks()` until data is ready to be `recv()`'d (or `poll()` timesout).  Without `poll()`, you're always going to be doing `other_tasks()` with the possibility to read every time `other_tasks()` finishes.  The question that sorta remains is, if there's work to be done that doesn't depend on the `recv()`, why not just do `other_tasks()` in another thread and have a dedicated network communications thread?